# Basic Oriented Object Modelization in PHP5

Tags: php, zend-framework, oop

I use zend framework and I would like to have your advice to modelize my classes.
I have 3 classes Patrimony.php Project.php and Version.php.
Version extends Project extends Patrmimony.
In other hand I have a folder structure like this `/data/patrimonies/projects/versions/`

I don't know if I have to use a Design Pattern or something like that, if patrimony have a variable $_project which contains an instance of project, how do I instanciate my class (`__construct()` params). In brief I am very confusing with OOP.

Please light me :-)

`class Admin_Model_Patrimony
{
}`

`class Admin_Model_Project extends Admin_Model_Patrimony
{
}`

`class Admin_Model_Version extends Admin_Model_Project
{
}`

Comment: I don't really get your question. But note that inheritance may not be the best solution. Composition could be better. E.g. what is the the purpose of `Version`? If a project can exist in multiple versions I would design this as a composition.

Comment: Ok thx for the tips I will look at this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I have look to the composition pattern and it seems it is interessant when you want to compose with different number of leaves. In my case There are always one patrimony one project and one version for any entities.

My goal is sometimes I just use informations about a patrimony othertimes I only needs information about project.

I show you how I have design my classes, see the last lines for execution process and expected values.
I think this code doesn't work so how do I do to set variable of the parents when I instanciate a child?

`// Version


class Version extends Project


private $this->_patId;


private $this->_proId;


private $this->_verId;


{


public function __contruct($patrimonyId, $projectId, $versionId)


{ 


    $this->_patId = $patrimonyId;


    $this->_proId = $projectId;


    $this->_verId = $versionId;


}


public function getVersionId()


{


return $this->_verId;


}`



`// Project


class Project extends Patrimony


private $this->_patId;


private $this->_proId;


{


public function __contruct($patrimonyId, $projectId)


{ 


    $this->_patId = $patrimonyId;


    $this->_proId = $projectId;


}


public function getProjectId()


{


return $this->_proId;


}`

`// Patrimony


class Patrimony


private $this->_patId;


{


public function __contruct($patrimonyId)


{ 


    $this->_patId = $patrimonyId;


}


public function getPatrimonyId()


{


return $this->_patId;


}




// Execution


$version = new Version(1,2,3);


$version->getVersionId(); // should return 1


$version->getProjectId(); // should return 2


$version->getPatrimonyId(); // should return 3`